# Debugging a Delphi app on Wine

Tags: delphi, debugging, wine

I have a Delphi Windows app that dies horribly under Wine - doesn't even get to creating the main form. Porting to Free Pascal is not an option for various reasons.

Can I debug under Wine using Delphi's native means? If not, can I debug under Wine using gdb, and if so, how do I feed the debug info in Delphi format (Turbo Debugger probably) to gdb?

Finally, how can I detect Wine from a program? The Wine FAQ says I should not, but I don't think that fixing my app is high on the Wine guys' priority list, so I'd rather take the matters in my own hands.

I did not write the app, but I have the sources and a copy of Delphi.

Answer (score 2):

I do believe you should be able to debug with **gdb**, but I don't know how you would feed all the Delphi sources to it.  You would need to include all debug information in your EXE (including External debugger) to get started though.

I would recommend you get a logging utility that supports logging over TCP/IP.  Two good ones are [SmartInspect](http://www.gurock.com/smartinspect/) and [CodeSite](http://www.raize.com/DevTools/CodeSite/Default.asp).  Combine those with a stack tracing utility like the [JCL](http://jcl.delphi-jedi.org/) provides and you might find it is a better solution then attaching the debugger anyway.

- [image: CodeSite]
  <sub>(source: [raize.com](https://www.raize.com/DevTools/images/CS_Logo.png))</sub>
- [image: Smart Inspect]
  <sub>(source: [gurock.com](http://www.gurock.com/images/feature/smartinspect-logo.png))</sub>

Good luck on detecting Wine though.  I would be curious to see what you come up with.  Seems like it should be possible though.

Answer (score 1):

You *might* be able to get the remote debugger to connect to the Wine app (never tried it), but that's asking a lot of Wine.

The first thing I'd try is using a stack tracing utility like the [JCL](http://jcl.delphi-jedi.org/) debugging extensions. A stack trace may give you enough information to fix the issue without having to get debugging working under Linux.

Comment: That's not unlike the printf()-based debugging of ages past :) Which is an option, I admit. Just not a pleasant one.

Comment: As a debugging tool, yes. As a way of getting postmortems from customers or other cases which can be difficult to reproduce, it's priceless.

Comment: Right now my ambition is more humble - getting the damn thing to start and show the main window would be good enough. :) And the app is freeware, so rigorous customer support is not on my agenda. Thanks for the link though.

Answer (score 0):

If you've got the source code, then recompile with a bunch of debug messages in and try running it like you'd do on windows.

Wine has a lot of API's that are left unimplemented and you may have some luck installing extra packages at random with winetricks.

I had a similar problem using wine with our Delphi App, I needed to install the ODBC manager, which doesn't come in by default before I could get the thing to work.

Comment: Oh, I read your comment and you're not too keen on printf debugging, oh well. It's probably only 1 or 2 things preventing your software from initializing so it's probably worth it.

Comment: Well, if there's no better option, then printf() is is. I was just hoping that the collective wizdom of StackOverflow had a better solution.